# Appium inspector is not launching for iOS App

Tags: ios, appium, appium-ios

I am unable to launch the appium inspector. It is displaying Instruments Usage Error: Specified target process is invalid: test.all instruments, version 7.3 (60133)

[image: iOS settings of Appium]

[image: General settings of appium]

```
Find the error log below
[iOSLog] [IOS_SYSLOG_ROW] Aug 24 17:24:36 iPhone-5C lockdownd[32] <Error>: CFStringGetCString error in locklog

[debug] [Instruments] [INST STDERR] Instruments Usage Error: Specified target process is invalid: test.all
instruments, version 7.3 (60133)
usage: instruments [-t template] [-D document] [-l timeLimit] [-i #] [-w device] [[-p pid] | [application [-e variable value] [argument ...]]]


[debug] [Instruments] Instruments exited with code 255

[Instruments] Error launching instruments: Instruments crashed on startup

[iOSLog] [IOS_SYSLOG_ROW] Aug 24 17:24:44 iPhone-5C notification_proxy[153] <Error>: 0x40081000 -[MNPLockdownConnection receiveMessage]: lockdown_receive_message error!
[iOSLog] [IOS_SYSLOG_ROW] Aug 24 17:24:44 iPhone-5C notification_proxy[153] <Error>: 0x40081000 -[MNPLockdownConnection receiveMessage]: lockdown_receive_message error!
[iOSLog] [IOS_SYSLOG_ROW] Aug 24 17:24:44 iPhone-5C DTServiceHub[201] <Warning>: Could not create service name
```

Comment: have yiu used the proper bundleid of the app

Comment: Yes, I am using the bundle id which is displaying in info.plist file

Answer (score 0):

In order to launch appium inspector, you will have to check prelaunch application and also the app path. You will   be able to launch the appium inspector then.